# Xamarin.Forms how can I save a JPG with a 8 bit colour depth?

Tags: image-processing, xamarin.forms, .net-core, .net-standard

I have spent all afternoon researching this but I have not been able to find a solution. For reasons out of my control when I send a photo to the web service I deal with it can only handle jpgs with a pixeldepth of 8 bits (don't ask). Typically the camera will return 24 bit pixel depth jpgs. My app is written in Xamarin.Forms (.NET Standard, not PCL) and is currently implemented on Android though iOS will be supported in the future. I have had a look at the following article regarding .NET core image processing (note I cannot use the System.Drawing namespace):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/

I have had a play with the follwing libraries but I have been unable to produce an 8 bit colour jpg with any of them:

- SkiaSharp
- ImageSharp
- FreeImage-dotnet-core

Has anyone got any ideas? I can implement platform specific solutions via the DependencyService as long as there is a solution for both Android and iOS. Thanks.

Comment: you may need to do this natively in each platform and expose it to Forms via DependencyService

Comment: I think you are getting *"confuzzled"* **TM** by the terminology! When folks say an 8-bit JPEG, they are referring to 8-bits per channel for each of 3 channels so that is effectively 24-bits.